# Running Find command from the directory vs. another directory

Tags: find, mv

I am doing something wrong but cannot figure out what it is. I am trying to move all files in the folder (folder A) to another folder (folder B) without any subdirectories and excluding certain files

When I am in the folder I run...

```
cd folderA
find . -path './*' -prune -not \( -name "file1.php" -o -name "file2.txt" \) -type f -exec mv -f {} ~/folderB/ \;
```

That works great. But I want to run the above find command in a bash script and do no want to have to go to the folder so I tried...

```
find ~/folderA/ -path './*' -prune -not \( -name "file1.php" -o -name "file2.txt" \) -type f -exec mv -f {} ~/folderB/ \;
```

And nothing! What am I doing wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

After stripping the above command down, I found the issue. for some reason `-path './*' -prune` does not work outside of the direct folder. Here is the command I used to get it to work outside the folder itself...

```
find ~/folderA/ -maxdepth 1 -not \( -name "file1.php" -o -name "file2.txt" \) -type f -exec mv -f {} ~/folderB/ \;
```

Again, not sure way `-maxdepth 1` would work over the other method, but it did.

FYI... if you want to go further down into the subdirectories you can by changing the `1` value